# Cleanup "dirty" Google Analytics Custom Variables Keys?

Tags: google-analytics

Is there a way I can filter out/prevent the following type of unexpected behavior in my Custom Variables (ideally there would only one row of `1. Page Type`)?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the data is in the report it's final. There's no way to remove that data from Google Analytics anymore. You can always use a report filter to remove them if they want, but most of the time it's better to just ignore them.

You can try to keep that information from coming in again. Just make sure that all the places where you set the custom variable use the same name for the custom variable. You might have some pages that use the 2 words together, so just look at the pages where that custom variable was set and try to change it to use "Page Type" instead of "PageType".

The other ones have such a small number that they may be from some testing it on a dev environment. So you just need to ignore them.

Answer (score 10):

You can delete the unexpected custom variables by using:

```
_deleteCustomVar()
```

This method deletes the variable assigned to the supplied index, if one exists. For example, you might set a visitor-level custom variable and later decide that you no longer want to use this visitor-level variable.

```
_gaq.push(['_deleteCustomVar', 1]);
```

Here are the details:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiBasicConfiguration#_gat.GA_Tracker_._deleteCustomVar

Comment: Thanks!  I was originally looking for a way to delete the ones already in the GA Report.  This won't fix that issue, but is a good solution to the question title!

Comment: If it doesn't delete the variable from the Report, what does it actually do?  I'm confused.

Comment: This method deletes the variable assigned to the supplied index. In other words, yes it deletes the variable from the Report.